# DRF how to make register api view only available for my react app

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

So I can't figure out how to make this registration view can only accept registrations from my react app. Currently, anybody can put values in my fields and then my API will accept it. I would like to make it restricted in some way so that it only accepts values through the apps that I allow.

serializers.py

```
# Serializer for user info for the registration API
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User # for the User model, use get_user_model for custom
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    # override create method
    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
            )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = ''
```

Comment: you simply have this endpoint be accessible only to authorized users ... an then check some permission ... you typically use some sort of token authentication to authenticate against a rest api

Comment: But what if the user is not authorized yet? Since they still need to register through the app?

Comment: then grant the app a token that it can use to hit the endpoint ... but be forewarned it will be in js or something on the clientside so a savy user will be able to extract it and use it if they want ... whats the problem if its just registration ... if some company wants to register people for your service i would think that would be a lot of work for them with no real benefit to doing so, well maybe some benefit to you since they would then have to somehow be steered to your service anyway

Comment: You can have IP restriction, if your React app is on different server